# What would happen if you can't pay because your credit card stopped working?

Tags: canada, labor-law, payment

I'm interested in situations were you pay after you use or consume something (like eating at a restaurant or renting something). What would happen if your credit card stops working before you pay?

In my job I am given a company credit card. Once it stopped working (I called my manager and she said everyone was having issues) but I was able to pay out of my own pocket and get reimbursed. What would happen if I didn't want to or wasn't able to pay out of my own pocket?

Comment: @Nij that question is about the restaurant's machine not working. So the customer is willing and able to pay. Different here. That said, the accepted there answer probably covers the situation here.

Comment: Not sure why the down votes. It is a good question and a legal one. Maybe the second paragraph is too personal and specific. The question could be "What is the legal situation if my card does not work and I have no other method of payment on me."

Comment: It's the same question - the credit card is not working as a means of payment, and the question is predicated on the lack of other means of payment. Sorry, but this is a clear duplicate.

Comment: It's getting downvotes because it is (not even the first this month) duplicate of an existing question with high quality answers, that are found easily by searching for "credit card". Lack of research = downvotes. @Damila

Comment: I thought it might be different because it's a company credit card and I'm doing something for work. Hypothetically  the company might be committing a crime if they cancel the credit card knowing someone is trying to use it.

Comment: There's a point in the question "what if my company credit card doesn't work and I don't want to pay". The restaurant has a contract with _you_. You are responsible for the payment. Whether you want to pay or not doesn't matter, you _have_ to.

Answer (score 0):

You would be civil and make a plan with the other party (e.g., restaurant) to pay later.
If one side is not civil (e.g., you say "sorry" and just leave), that side is a criminal
or a defendant in civil court.